# Code first one to one select query

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, one-to-one

I try using Code First but I have some troubles, I think I forget or miss something ...
I have two pretty simple models : (a car have one FuelType, it's a one to one relation)

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public Fuel FuelType { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class Fuel
{
    public int FuelID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My contextClass :

```
public class CarDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fuel> Fuels { get; set; }

    public CarDbContext()
        : base("CarDbConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CarDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CarDbContext>());
    }
```

And my main program :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<Car> maListe;

        using (var ctx = new CarDbContext())
        {
            var car = from c in ctx.Cars
                          select c;

            maListe = car.ToList<Car>();
        }

        foreach (Car c in maListe)
            Console.WriteLine("Car: {0} {1}", c.CarName, c.FuelType.Name);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

In my console, I can see CarName but not the FuelType.Name of the car.

I tried few things like changing my query to this :

```
  var car = from c in ctx.Cars.Include("Fuels")
            select c;
```

But I get an exception :

> A specified Include path is not valid. The Entity Type 'Car' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Fuels'

Does someone can explain to me what I did wrong or what I forget ?

Answer (score 1):

You have navigation property named `FuelType`:

```
var cars = ctx.Cars.Include("FuelType"); // not `Fuels`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (thanks @haim770 too).
I tried this but I've got a "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" Exception when it tries to : `maListe = car.ToList<Car>();` Should I use a generic list or something else?

Comment: @anthoLB29 it's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing complete code, but you don not have to specify type of sequence parameter when saving data to list. Simply use `cars.ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to 'eager-load' `FuelType`, try:

```
var car = from c in ctx.Cars.Include("FuelType")
```

Alternatively, you can mark it as `virtual` and have `FuelType` 'lazy-loaded' for you:

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public virtual Fuel FuelType { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it's a one-to-one relation ? a FuelType is only associated with one car ?

Anyway, in order to make a **one-to-one relation** you have to include a navigation property for the Principal entity in your Dependent entity, as follow:

```
public class CarDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CarDbContext()
        : base("CarDbConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CarDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CarDbContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fuel> Fuels { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public virtual Fuel FuelType { get; set; }    // set as virtual
}

public class Fuel
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Car")]                      // primary and foreign key
    public int FuelID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }          // must include a navigation property for the Principal entity
}
```

But if it's a **one-to-many relationship**, you can handle it as follow:

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public int FuelTypeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FuelTypeID")]
    public virtual Fuel FuelType { get; set; }
}

public class Fuel
{
    public int FuelID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CarDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CarDbContext()
        : base("CarDbConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CarDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CarDbContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fuel> Fuels { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for answering me.
Your answers really make me progress in EF understanding.
By the way I was really stuck with the "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" Exception.
I changed so many things in my code than now it works but unfortunately I cannot understand why :(